# Flutter video_player in TabBarView

Tags: dart, flutter

Could anyone point me to some sample code which allows a video to be displayed in TabBarView? Up to now it's throwing an error when I try to load the video in a tab:

> I/flutter ( 5591): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   I/flutter ( 5591): The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
>   I/flutter ( 5591): 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart': Failed assertion: line 683 pos 12: 'pixels !=
>   I/flutter ( 5591): null': is not true.
>   ...

Answer (score 0):

The code below shows youtube video player in the TabBarVew. You need to update pubspec.yaml file for youtube video package like:

```
dependencies:
  youtube_player: ^0.6.0
```

A sample code for your requirement is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player/youtube_player.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(StartPage());
}

class StartPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: "New Task",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: new HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{

  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = new TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("GrubX"),
        bottom: TabBar(
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
          labelColor: Colors.amber,
          tabs: [
          new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.call)),
          new Tab(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.chat),
          ),
          new Tab(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.notifications),
          )
        ],
        controller: _tabController,
        indicatorColor: Colors.white,
        indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,),
        bottomOpacity: 1,
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
          children: [
        new YoutubePlayer(
          source: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gb2xJ-GMKmo",
          quality: YoutubeQuality.HD,
          aspectRatio: 16/9,
          showThumbnail: true,),
        new YoutubePlayer(
          source: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gb2xJ-GMKmo",
          quality: YoutubeQuality.HD,
          aspectRatio: 16/9,
          showThumbnail: true,),
        new YoutubePlayer(
          source: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gb2xJ-GMKmo",
          quality: YoutubeQuality.HD,
          aspectRatio: 16/9,
          showThumbnail: true,),
      ],
      controller: _tabController,),
    );
  }
}
```

You can use video_player package instead of youtube_player if you want to play videos from your phone.